# I can't read db.transiction (WEBsql, javascript, jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-sql

In my

`$(document).ready(function() {...}` 
i have my button 
`$('#saveDate').click(function(){
         insertDateOfProcedure();
         showRecords();
         });`

it have 2 function, the first is

```
   function insertRecordPaziente()
    {   
    var nome=$('#id').val();
    var bday=$('#bday').val();
    var clinicalNotes=$('#clinicalNotes').val();
    var fkPaziente=null;
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO paziente (nomePaziente, bDay, sex, clinicalNotes ) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)' , [nome, bday, radioButtonSex(), clinicalNotes] );        
    });         
}
```

the second is

```
function saveFK(){
db.transaction(function (tx) {
alert("??");
tx.executeSql("select seq from sqlite_sequence where name='paziente';", [], function (tx, result)
            { 
            alert("12334");
            dataset = result.rows; 
            if(dataset.length > 0)
            {
            for (var i = 0, item = null; i < dataset.length; i++)
            { 
                alert("ciao Mondo b");
                item = dataset.item(i);                                                     
                console.log(item['seq']);
                 fkPaziente=item['seq'];
                alert("fkPaziente:   "+fkPaziente); 
                return fkPaziente;            
            }            
            } else {alert("problemi con transiction");}              
        }); 
});
}
```

when i click "#saveDate" only the function "insertRecordPaziente" is performed"!
the compiler read saveFK() until db.transiction...

I have declared my db  when the script start

```
var db=openDatabase("hospital2", "1.0", "hospitalDatabase", 200000);
```

Can you help me?